# ERROR: Could not determine artifacts for androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0: No cached version available for offline mode

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I want to make an implementation of the library of `card-view` and library of `recycleview` but the following error shows up after building or syncing the project:

```
ERROR: Could not determine artifacts for androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0: No cached version available for offline mode
```

What steps do I need to take to eliminate this sync error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the following path in your Android Studio:

`File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Gradle`

Then under `Global Gradle Settings`, uncheck the `Offline work` option. Hit Apply and then Okay. Sync the project again, make sure you have Internet Connectivity and it should work.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

As answered by @SaadAakash I didn't find any *offline work* check box under Gradle in Android Studio Preference in my Mac.

After searching for a while I found another way to switch off *offline work*

Go to **View** menu in toolbar and navigate to **Tool Windows** and select **Gradle**
[image]

Gradle pane will open in right side, toggle offline work switch
[image]

and sync the Gradle once again.

Hope it should work!